# regular expression for conditions in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have the following array

```
myArray = ["zen", "allen", 37045456, 3604912, "Street45#13-55", "Street67#60B-30"]
```

or if is possible (i thinks is harder than before one)

```
myArray = [37045456, 3604912, "zen", "Street45#13-55", "allen",  "Street67#60B-30"]
```

in this case has not order, i need the order

these arrays has 6 positions

I need to join the phones and the address to get a final array like this

with 4 positions

and set the name and lastname first, after phone and after address

```
["zen", "allen", 37045456 3604912, "Street45#13-55 Street67#60B-30"]
```

I have been tried the following

```
const digits_only = string => [...string].every(c => '0123456789'.includes(c));

for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
  if(digits_only(myArray[i].trim())){
  console.log("====== PHONE ======", myArray[i])
  }
}
```

to get the phones

thanks in advances

Comment: Will the array be consistent? Or, its values can come in all short of order?
Also, are you creating the array? If so, why can't you store an array of object in which each object holds the information as you want then to display?